# Should i use push notification or local notifications?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, localnotification

I'm creating my first app in react native and would like users to receive a notification based on a date they set within the app.

I would like the app to send the notifications even when the app isn't open.

My question is, should i use push notifications or local notifications for this? Any advice would be helpful

I'm yet to implement a solution because i'm new to mobile development

Comment: If it is notifications that you want to display based off of a date that is set in the app, I would say local notifications would be the way to go.  You would leverage normal push notifications if you needed it to occur if an external transaction would occur (say a payment processed on your account, or someone sent you a message).  Push Notifications are a little harder to setup since you need to handle  setup for apple and google push notifications to be sent out.

Comment: @Sgreulic so i have users logging to do list items into the app which i save to a database. They can set deadlines in the app too, based on your reply, i guess i can use local notifications?

Comment: Yea I would say so.  Give that a shot first before going through the hassle of setting up Push Notifications through servers .